# Platinum Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I think it would be cool to implement (yet another :D) level of badges for the StackOverflow site. Perhaps a so called **Platinum** badge.

These would have to be extremely rare and only given out for extremely special accomplishments. A type of Medal of Honor for StackOverflow users.

Would anyone else be interested in this? Feel free to post ideas for types of Platinum badges.

Comment: And what benefit would come from that?

Comment: To be honest, it's all in the spirit of having fun but really for the same reason we have gold badges. As something to work towards.

Comment: @codedude, so you don't get enough fun with gold badges?

Comment: Perhaps we could have just a single Platinum badge, awarded for having a user id whose prime factorization is 2^7 * 3 * 59.

Comment: haha whatever...maybe it's not such a great idea after all. :) Downvote to your heart's content

Comment: Already suggested almost five years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges.

Comment: Proposed Badge: 360 No Scope - Ask a question that receives 360 upvotes before it is closed as being off-topic for being outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Compass No, 360 means a full circle. So the question also needs to go through at least one close-reopen cycle. :P

Comment: This is a great question, even if the result is a resounding "no", the answer(s) can nail it down. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @MrBoJangles - On Meta voting is used to indicate Agreement / Disagreement with OP's idea.  They do not impact reputation since Meta sites have none of their own.

Comment: @PM77-1 In that case, the votes are completely appropriate. Good to know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> These would have to be extremely rare and only given out for extremely special accomplishments

Have you seen:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold

I believe most of them already fall under your criteria for the suggested *Platinum* badges, their being rare and special accomplishments.

Taking a few Gold badge examples:

- Question favorited by 100 users
- Asked a question with 10,000 views
- Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score
- Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP
  addresses
  etc

How much "rarer" and "special" (aka harder) were you thinking...?
Even some of the Silver ones are tricky and need to be worked at intentionally.

Perhaps if you have some good ideas for new badges, they could be considered to be added to Gold/Silver.

But I disagree with a proposal to implementing "*Platinum badges*" simply because it "sounds cool".
Not without some suggested badge criteria ideas which would at least *arguably* be suited for introducing a new badge colour.

Also, you have 4 silver badges. I think you have plenty to earn yet before worrying about even harder ones ;)

Comment: You're probably right.

Comment: You mentioned one that's been awarded 131.2k times on [so]...

Comment: @Dukeling - How many questions "asked in the last 6 months" have had 10,000 views? A lot of the badges (not just Gold) were much much easier to earn in the early days of the site, as people asked the very popular/frequently asked questions which still pick up views/votes. Where now most questions are either a dupe of those popular questions, or aren't as popular as they're specific to a particular scenario. A lot of the recent people earning "Famous Question" are from questions asked years ago.

Comment: That badge being awarded to old questions more often doesn't necessarily mean it's difficult to get, just that it takes long, or involves lucking out. We can't really say new questions will be less popular 5 years from now than those asked 5 years ago are now.

Comment: You're saying 5 years to get a badge is "not difficult"?

Comment: Here's an oddity I don't understand. 15,000+ views since 11 October last year. Does this look like it would be "popular" outside of an SO niche? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792432/compare-two-files-and-write-it-to-match-and-nomatch-files So, it must be easy to get lots of views, just not easy to know how, or why.

Comment: @BillWoodger that question is 5 years old. I'd take a guess that any recent popularity is the title "compare two files", which is a popular search term, but not many votes as it's not basic file comparison question/answer. So people quickly leave the question

Comment: @James I think you may be right, although I don't know why such an increase in the last 12 months. I was assuming the tag `jcl` would not attract views, but realise now that the casual searcher won't even know that `jcl` means anything, will just skip that noise, and just dip in and jump back quickly with a "what on Earth was that!" expression of some type reverberating in their ears :-)

Answer (score 3):

The only really useful application of "platinum badges" that I see would be platinum review badges, to give  a new goal and incentive to those folks who already have a gold badge due to having completed more than the 1000 reviews in a given queue.

And even then, it would only really be useful in the longest queue of all: the Close Votes queue. The other queues don't really need much more attention than they already garner.

Yeah, I can see that. Having a **Close Votes "Curator" Platinum badge** would serve a purpose. Maybe set it at 5000 reviews.

Comment: Or just allow multiple rewards of the existing gold badge at specified levels for that queue.

Comment: I'm in favor of such a badge....

Comment: You do realize that the addition of review badges pretty much killed the entire review system, to the point where it's still trying to recover from the damage done, no?  Adding a new super special review badge is likely going to be enough to be the last nail in the coffin of the review queues, rendering them so unusable as to become a net harm to the site.

Comment: @Servy: Sweeping statements aside, badges = goals, and goals are pretty widely recognised as a useful tool to motivate people to do stuff. I don't think I would have strained to do 1k reviews in any queue without those goals. But sure, the badge definitions should be tweaked to mitigate the unintended consequences — if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett The review badges add *hundreds* of *extremely* low quality, and often outright abusive, reviewers, each making hundreds of bad reviews, all to get a badge.  Almost every single quality reviewer I've spoken to has stated they were in any way motivated by the badges.  I'm sure there are some, but they are completely dwarfed by the poor reviewers, especially given that we just don't have the tools to effectively deal with them.  It's not worth a few dozen good reviewers if it means adding hundreds of terrible ones at the same time.

Comment: @Servy: How do you *know* all this? Beyond anecdotes, is there evidence supporting these numbers? Because yeah, if there is, then let's get rid of harmful badges. If.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Badges were added, then review went to crap.  Bad reviewers had a tendency to stop as soon as they got their badge.  Good reviewers have largely stated they weren't motivated (at least not strongly) by the badge, bad reviewers have stated that they *are* motivated by the badge.  Many of the particularly good reviewers were reviewing when there was no badge, those reviewers starting after the badges were introduced were *dramatically* poorer at reviewing, even after reviewing a large number of items.

Comment: @Servy: I'm still wondering how you know all this. I'd like to see the evidence behind your interpretation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Spends some time looking through the many meta discussions taking place around the time when they were added, and in the months following.

Comment: @Servy: I have now done that, and found no broad agreement with your arguments. Except for the "[brief, horrible period between when badges for review were introduced and when the audits were implemented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260350/119775)", I don't see much complaining about this at all. It seems like the audits are catching the bad reviewers. I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Audits are catching the worst of the worst, the people not even reading the reviews and only blindly pushing "approve" as fast as they can.  That's moving from just "bad" to "abusive".  The audits can deal with "abusive", or at least some of it, but not the "bad" reviews.

Comment: @Servy: What is a "bad" reviewer if not someone who blindly pushes the buttons? If you read over everything and considered why it would be approved or not and then picked appropriately, you're a "good" reviewer, are you not?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare No, you are not. The specifics will of course vary based on the queue.  In the suggested edit queue, there are rules and guidelines for what types of edits are appropriate, and what aren't.  Approving an edit that violates the rules, even if you took the time to read it and really thought it was a good edit, is still a bad review.  If you're approving spam in the first/last post queue, not voting to close questions that meet a close criteria in the close queue, marking non answers as okay in LQP, etc. are all things a bad reviewer can do while still passing audits.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare There are a lot of actions in review queues that are very much situations that have an objective correct and an objectively wrong answer.  Yes, there are some situations that are inherently opinion based, but the queues (intentionally) are generally not centered around those types of actions.  When you decide how to vote on a post you've just read there is no objectively correct answer; you can vote how you want, and whatever you choose is fine.  That's just not the case of the majority of review actions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That actually happened