# Are we supposed to flag bad reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Today I saw a suggested edit which seemed to me to be clearly bad (which I don't want to link, to avoid any sort of public shaming). The only change was removing a period in the title, and the edit comment was

> i want to integrate wechat in my web application. i cant find the sample codes. help me...?

Fortunately, this was rejected by three out of four reviewers, but I wasn't sure if I should flag something because of the one bad approval. Looking through meta, I found a few related questions/answers

- [Let us bring an end to the “robo-reviewer” war: Phase 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260350/2499035)
- [Should we be able to flag suggested edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265950/2499035)
- [Should I bring the behaviour of an obvious robot-reviewer to the attention of the moderators, and how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157585/should-i-bring-the-behaviour-of-an-obvious-robot-reviewer-to-the-attention-of-th/157589)

However, these don't make the answer clear to me. The one clear-cut situation was that it seems I should flag if I can see a consistent pattern of bad edits being approved by a reviewer, but that isn't the case here. I glanced at a few of the user's other reviews, and nothing seemed egregiously bad.

So is this the kind of thing that I should raise a custom flag for, or is it too unimportant to waste the moderators' time with?

Comment: Bad reviews happen. Let the system/mods take care of robo-reviewers. You don't need to dig through someone's activity and manage this yourself.

Comment: Isn't this the reason each edit requires multiple reviews?

Comment: I don't really plan to dig through someone else's activity. I was more wondering about when I see a potential issue like this while I'm using the site normally. Would it be better to point it out so the mods can take appropriate action (if necessary), or leave them alone to deal with more important issues?

Comment: I'd love to be able to point out someone approving a ***blatantly*** bad edit such as the one the OP is describing. Mods can't *catch 'em all*, so to speak.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Possibly, but it depends on the specific circumstances.

If you see a clear pattern of a particular user making careless reviews, and suspect them of abusing the review queues, you can flag for that. However, you need to provide us evidence of this abuse (links to specific bad reviews) if you want to be sure we see what you did.

Particularly egregious reviews can also be worth flagging over. If you see someone approving obvious spam or vandalism, even a single instance of that, flag that post or another post of theirs and provide a link to the review or spam post in the flag. I tend to act on even lone examples of reviews like this.

If it's a single borderline review, and nothing else in the user's immediate review history jumps out at you, it might not be worth flagging over. Even good reviewers can make minor mistakes or have differences of opinion with the community as to what's acceptable. It's the more harmful behavior of approving spam or patterns of inattentiveness that we want to focus on.

Comment: @GrantWinney - Yeah, this is a case where I'd want to look at some more examples of bad reviews before I decided to apply a short review ban or something more. By itself, this could just be a one-time mistake or slip up, and a single review can do less harm in the suggested edits queue than in First Posts or Late Answers (where a single approval can allow spam onto the site).

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR - if you suspect a user's reviewing actions are letting trash that should immediately be removed onto the site, or otherwise making edits/allowing defacing edits to posts, then you're more than welcome to flag it.

There's a couple of bits here to consider first that the system does automatically:

- if a user fails audits, they can end up suspended from reviewing
- if enough other reviewers in the suggested edit queue reject edits, the edit proposer can end up suspended from having suggested edit access...
- disagreement in the VLQ queue also ends up in the moderator queue for review

Now - while the above doesn't solve everything - it does filter out a lot of things that users don't have to and shouldn't have to be worried about. Don't forget that the things you do see "slip through the net" are albeit it frustrating, but only a small fraction of what's going on.

Moderators will also go through the queues and look at audit failures, people that seem to review every post in a second etc... and where necessary will issue manual suspensions from review.

Comment: `people that seem to review every post in a second` How is that possible? The review buttons take one second to become available, therefore there's supposed to be no way to review X posts in less than X seconds.