# Should the review freeze time be increased?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I noticed [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80858/aloneguid) who is systematically approving edits, even terrible ones. [All](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11062579) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11062253) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11062567) [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11044055) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11062732) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11069900) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11069956) [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11070104) by this reviewer, and he of course [fail his audits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11062859) too.

When you look at his review timestamps, it seems that the user just waits until the approve button is enabled to click it - he surely doesn't have the time to read anything in 3 seconds:

```
2016-01-29 08:21:48
2016-01-29 08:21:43
2016-01-29 08:21:39
2016-01-29 08:21:36
2016-01-29 08:21:33
2016-01-29 08:21:29
2016-01-29 08:21:26
```

I don't have clear evidence of that, but I think he's doing the same for his LQP reviews (all posts "looks ok" so far).

I custom-flagged one of the edit to warn moderators about this, but considering this behavior is pretty common there might be a better way to prevent this:

**How about increasing the freeze time on the review buttons?** I don't feel like there is any review you could possibly correctly accomplish in 2 seconds. Maybe force reviewers to stay for 10 seconds on the review page will force them to read? With a little message while the freeze is running, something like:

> Please wait x seconds to review this edit. Use this time to read the edit thoroughly.

I'm aware that after failing few audits the user will be banned from review, but in order to educate users to properly review, this might be a solution to avoid the "robo reviewing".

What do you think about this?

Comment: After failing too many review audits, he will be automatically banned from reviews, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Gothdo : It could be that he didn't know that. I certainly didn't know that.

Comment: That is exactly why there is a limit to reviews per day, and a review doesn't depend on one person.

Comment: @Gothdo the question is what _we_ can do. Sure, you can wait until the system catches it, but then the harm is already done. The _problem_ is that there is yet another user who uses this site for the shiny badges, and couldn't care less for quality. We better get rid of such users. That being said, this is a duplicate of many questions.

Comment: @Gothdo I'm not sure you understand my question. When ***noticing*** an user who's on the path to be banned from review, what's the right course of action to take? Can't we educate the reviewer, sent him some warning before he get banned to get it back in the right path?

Comment: @CodeCaster I would be interested if you could point me to those duplicates - I searched before asking on meta and didn't find any question  helpfull.

Comment: You can @-comment on any of their posts. Or contact them in chat. But if a user has ignored the "STOP! Look and Listen" that they've had (apparently) multiple times.... I doubt it'll help.

Comment: See [Are we supposed to flag bad reviews?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280649/are-we-supposed-to-flag-bad-reviews): _"If you see a clear pattern of a particular user making careless reviews, and suspect them of abusing the review queues, you can flag for that"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fair enough. I will flag one of the failed review, though that doesn't really answer the second question.

Comment: That's what you get for asking two completely different questions at the same time.  #2 sounds like a decent FR.  You should flesh that out and submit it for review.

Comment: Limiting the speed won't help. Worse, it will make it harder to spot the robots - if you see 10 or more approvals in a minute, you _know_ it is a robo-reviewer, and you can take action. Don't take this clue away from us!

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think it address robo-reviewers only - a lot of poor reviews are not done by robo reviewers. And I thought the audits were there for this exact intent: spot the robo-reviewers. This will not be changed by increasing the freeze time.

Comment: @vard Either way, I don't think slowing reviewers down will help. We need to educate the reviewers. There are a few feature requests for that, but AFAIK Stack Exchange hasn't acted upon them yet. At least not openly.

Answer (score 6):

When they consistently fail the audits, you don't have to do anything... it will catch up with them, and they will get a well-deserved review suspension.

You could also contact them, and talk with them. Whether or not this is going to be effective depends on the user.

If you suspect deliberate abuse, or if they won't listen when you talk with them... you can also flag them for moderator attention. You find a few recent, bad reviews - then use a custom moderator flag on one of their posts.

Limiting the speed with which we can do reviews is not going to help. Robo-reviewers will simply review as fast as the system lets them. What could help is better audits, and perhaps better guidance for reviewers.