# Who reviews the reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-abuse

Note: I am not including a link because the purpose of this post is not to call anybody out.

I recently edited a question. The user had misspelled the word "within" in the post's title. I looked at the pending review, to find out one of the reviewers rejected the edit:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Two other reviewers have approved the edit. When looking at the stats on the reviewer who rejected the edit:

> [Reviewer] has approved 378 edit suggestions and rejected 510 edit
>   suggestions and improved 5 edit suggestions

I have not checked the exact statistics for edit approvals, but this user's reject percentage seems several standard deviations above the average. And with a pretty large sample size at that.

In this case, it the review process will succeed because of the fact that the other reviewers approved the edit, overriding the reject. But this would not always be the case.

What type of measures are in place to make sure the review permission is not being abused? If a user rejects enough edits that other users approve, will he or she get flagged for serial edit rejection?

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that that user's rejections are above average, but that's because the vast majority of reviewers approve content that they shouldn't.  It's hard enough to get obvious spam/vandalism rejected, let alone just bad/inappropriate edits.

Comment: Maybe the reviewer misvoted because a cat bumped into their arm when they were clicking the vote button? (No, really! I did misvote once because one of my cats bumped into my arm when I was clicking to vote and I ended up clicking the wrong button.)

Comment: @Louis That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Gothdo (user who edited this question's title) clearly did not understand/appreciate the comic pun ;)

Comment: Side note: Single word changes are rarely worth time of 4-5 people it takes to get it approved so rejecting such change is fair (preferably reject and edit). Better example would help to build a case (and 800 reviews is not large number... maybe that person only acts on questionable reviews found organically monitoring questions instead of seating in edit queue)

Comment: The typical bad reviewer on Stack Overflow has too many *approve* votes, not reject.

Comment: @Servy I have been looking through some revision histories and you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an automated system to block bad reviewers (often called robo-reviewers)—[**review audits**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work). If someone fails too many of them, they will get automatically suspended from reviewing for some period of time.

Moderators can also manually suspend users from reviewing. If you think that some post was reviewed incorrectly, you can flag it for moderator intervention and explain the situation, or you can post a question on Meta about it.

Comment: I have doubts about the question that implies that having a lot of rejections is a bad thing, as they need to *reviewed*. Your only reference to that seems to be in your last paragraph where you explain that if I'm not caught by review audits an moderator will suspend me for rejecting to many stuff. Is that correct?

Comment: About flagging, I'll quote an older answer of mine: ["If it's a single borderline review, and nothing else in the user's immediate review history jumps out at you, it might not be worth flagging over. Even good reviewers can make minor mistakes or have differences of opinion with the community as to what's acceptable. It's the more harmful behavior of approving spam or patterns of inattentiveness that we want to focus on."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280686/19679)

Comment: @rene No, I'm not saying that. If someone for example skipped all good suggested edits, and rejected the bad ones, they wouldn't be suspended from reviewing by a moderator. By "reviewing incorrectly" I mean not only rejecting good edits, but also approving bad edits.