# How can I provide feedback on poor Community comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, community-user

Recently I've seen Community comments like

> Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Overall, I like it, it's good! But sometimes the community user puts them on a question where they're not really relevant.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68985680/903061), for example, is essentially a typo, the asker was trying to combine the first to arguments of a function into one argument. I commented with the correct syntax, and voted to close the question as a typo. The asker thanked me  in another comment. Then the Community comment popped up. I tried flagging it, but even though I have over 100k rep and a gold badge in one of the question's tags, I just get a message that

> This comment will be automatically removed by the system when the post is corrected.

Is there any way to help the system learn when these comments aren't useful?

Comment: “Community“ comments are picked by users on review. You seem to think these comments are chosen by some sort of AI. That’s not the case. You can’t “help the system learn”. There are human users evaluating these posts and using the “share feedback” button.

Comment: What community AI? Every single one of those comments is generated because a human made resulting selection indicating the question needed more detail.  If a question was caused by a typo it should be closed.  Unfortunately, the list of reasons, that generate the community is limited.  So reviewers deal with what we have, which is a shame, since it’s brand new.

Comment: Welcome to the most recent update to review queues, I guess. Behind each of those comments is a real user (although they won't know if you replied unless they followed the post) + the inability to flag those is literally a bug. The comments are also canned and, frankly, not well-worded (they could've at least looked at what users of the legendary ARC userscript use, but alas), so your frustration is more than understandsble.

Comment: I suspect that a fair bit of it may be related to review "credit". Unless I'm missing something, in order to get "credit" for a review, a reviewer must select "Looks OK", "Edit", or "Share Feedback", and the options under Share Feedback may not be the most appropriate for the circumstance. Since flags and "traditional" comments don't count for reviews made, I'm guessing a lot of reviewers are shoehorning feedback to get the review credit.

Comment: Imagine how weird code-related comments are on sites like English Language & Usage... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369111/334566

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the linked duplicate does not address the question of _How can I provide feedback_ on said comments.

Answer (score 4):

First, as noted in the comments, these are selected by humans in the [First questions review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions).  So any case where they're incorrect is an incorrect review by a human.  With that in mind:

If it's not egregiously bad, you should probably just flag the comment, either as "No longer needed" or with a custom flag explaining why it's wrong (such as the fact that you were able to diagnose the typo here).  **Note: this is currently not possible** (and moderators cannot delete the comments even if you flag the post separately), but [these issues will be fixed Soon™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/165261) and this advice will become accurate.

If it's egregiously wrong or you notice a pattern of bad reviews by the same person (you can check the post's [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/165261) to see the reviewer), you can flag the post itself for moderator attention and note that the review(s) was/were incorrect.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280686/208273) for more advice on when to flag bad reviews.