# Failed First Posts review audits are not cleared after suspension period has ended

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

So I failed two review audits and got suspended for two days …

I'm not complaining, but I want to understand why the system works the way it works.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28884296 – downvoted due to the question consisting mostly of a screenshot of code/error message. There's no code to reproduce and very little detail on how the Python environment is set up. No review effort visible besides a vague "I already reinstalled". Apparently, it is a highly-upvoted question. I stand corrected. Strike 1.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28891424 – I upvoted because the answer proposes a solution to the problem: Set "localizable" on the form to the default value. This totally looks like a valid answer to the question. The other 6 existing questions were hidden from the review view (to make the audit more difficult I guess?) Strike 2.

Well, everybody makes mistakes. I accept that. So I waited for a few days and started reviewing again after 4 days (i.e. another 2 days after the ban was lifted).

Today I am reviewing again, passing 2 (or more) (tricky) review audits. Then, an answer to a Robot framework question pops up to be reviewed: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28926252 – I upvote, because the question proposes to use A instead of B and links to the official documentation for the proposed method of the framework.

Bam… 1 single review audit failed within 3 days. I am now suspended for 4 days and the infobox shows me all 3 failed audits (so one audit from today and the 2 audits from 4 days ago which caused the first ban). So it only takes one vote counter to the consensus to be blocked for 4 days? That's a bit harsh … especially since the posted answer seems to actually answer the question in good faith.

Is this really the way that reviewing and the audits are supposed to work? It's not very motivating or educational to be blocked for several days for misjudging one single review. Doesn't SO live from community consensus to build a good knowledge library? Bad posts will automatically receive the right amount of down/closevotes.

At the same time, I miss more information about *why* a post is good/bad. The audit explanation is just "look, this was a good post, yet you downvoted". I get that, but *why* is it a good post? What exactly makes it good (or bad)? Without this information, this is training a human-based, distributed pattern-matching ML-algorithm – don't take this statement too seriously. There should be space for discussion of (opposing) review decisions.

Attention – Opinion: Why are users punished for trying to review posts and sometimes making questionable decisions or mistakes? Writing answers is not always possible, so time can be spent reviewing to increase the site's quality. Receiving day-long bans for a single wrong click is so very frustrating.
(Now knowing that the next mistake will ban me for 8+ days, I'd rather not spend time on reviewing at all in fear of choosing wrong on another post. It almost feels like help in reviewing is actually not needed/wanted.)
It is difficult to justify one's past decision(s) leading to a ban after the fact. Opening a meta post is an option, but so is simply stopping to visit the review queues altogether.

I found several other posts claiming similar problems with the review audits and suggesting improvements (although it looks like some of them or their answers have attracted massive amounts of downvotes):

- [The review audit/suspension system needs to be changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381961/the-review-audit-suspension-system-needs-to-be-changed)
- [Overly Severe Review Suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354555/overly-severe-review-suspension)
- [Review suspension progressive system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-suspension-progressive-system)
- [7 days block for not passing controversial audit - why my passed audits are completely ignored?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226815/7-days-block-for-not-passing-controversial-audit-why-my-passed-audits-are-comp)

Comment: i mean... often it isn't even a misjudging... the audit is just incorrect.

Comment: The first one is definitely incorrect in my eyes... the second one I am not so sure.

Comment: The second has two comments from past reviewers saying it isn't an answer, but if you cut out the first two sentences I agree that it's definitely a solution, if short and lacking in details. That's a harsh audit, at the very least.

Comment: Related: [Thesis: a downvote should never fail a first post audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit)

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm not even sure the comments were/are visible when reviewing the answer. I think for audits, most of the useful context is hidden (which I'm not sure is helping in making well-informed decisions)

Comment: *"Is this really the way that reviewing and the audits are supposed to work?"* - Yes, if you fail another audit after a review ban from audits then the ban duration will double. Your potential ban duration will halve every month you spend not failing audits... or something like that

Comment: @Nick o_O so if I fail another single audit in the next 3 weeks, I will be banned for 8 days straight? That's … harsh

Comment: @knittl Yep, the review audit progression system is different from the one in your last link, (that link's out of date), look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296) instead. You can keep failing audits until your ban is over a year long if you're not careful (and indeed, there _are_ users who have basically indefinite review bans at this point)

Comment: There's a reset period of 30 days. When you've been suspended, any failed audit within those 30 days will auto-suspend you. It doesn't matter if it's on another queue. You can 1. Be very very careful for 30 days or 2. Not review for 30 days :)

Comment: @Scratte There's a reset period for if you'll instantly get banned again, but it doesn't reset the duration, that still follows the gradual decay system

Comment: So instead of educating users and allowing them to apply their new reviewing skills, we rather block them almost indefinitely?

Comment: @knittl The fact that you are presented with the reviews that you failed is part of the education, no? It wasn't very long ago, that users had to find out that they were suspended by themselves. All the UI told them was "There are no review queue available to you" :D That's how I learned to type in "review" after the homepage URL in the address bar to get to reviews.

Comment: @Scratte yes, I see the education behind that. Nevertheless, I see little benefit in blocking users for having a different opinion on an answer/question. My latest failed audit is not a perfect answer, but it attempts to answer the quesion. It provides a solution and a link to the official documentation. Banning users for thinking it is an acceptable answer is suboptimal

Comment: I agree with you. The review system requires people to be able to see the future and have the same opinion as others will have. (For audits, it's not the future though, it's the past, which is easier to find out about :-)

Comment: The review system is fine, the audit system.... Ehhhhhh not so much

Comment: no, the review system is not fine. It asks for an opinion and expects that all have the same view on it,. which is fundamentally systemic wrong, as the criteria a much to vague and the questions and answers too many as to get every right, so bans should complitely banished forever

Comment: @nbk that's only in the Late answers queue, not in every queue. For instance, the suggested edits queue is straightforward when it comes to audits.

Comment: I remember an audit that I failed because I flagged as Needs Details or Clarity, the next say it was closed because it needed details or clarity.

Comment: @nbk that's.... The audit system, nothing in the review queues outside of audits expects you to act in a specific way and with the same views as others

Comment: @Nick The whole point of audits is that you don't know they're audits...

Comment: @Anonymous That's not correct, [audits are supposed to be easy, and sometimes blatant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug).

Comment: @zcoop98 I remember an audit that I failed because I flagged as Needs Details or Clarity, the next day it was closed because it needed details or clarity.

Comment: @Anonymous Saying what they're *supposed* to be, and what they sometimes *are*, are very different things.

Comment: @zcoop98 That's not what the comment was talking about.

Comment: @Anonymous Ummm ideally yeah, but I fail to see your point, or did you simply not read what I said? Audit system = bad, Review system otherwise = adequate

Comment: @Nick I thought you meant that regular reviewing won't ban you for your opinion, so it's fine that audits do.

Comment: @Nick i criticise the review system for year nothing has changed on the fundamental wrong system. The idea that we should help moderate, is correct and should be done further, but bans punoshes people for their opinion, and we don't live in 1984 even when some try to "correct" our views. 'it shoud be made an internel ignore system where bad reviewers would nit appear any more

Comment: @nbk *"it shoud be made an internel ignore system where bad reviewers would nit appear any more"* - So you're suggesting we shadowban people rather than tell people their banned? That's an _awfully stupid_ idea - but again, you're talking about the _AUDIT_ system, _not_ the review system. And no bans do _not_ just punish people for their opinion, they punish them for laziness and not objectively reviewing posts.

Comment: no i am talking about the revoew system, there is no audit afaik, at least i have never seen it

Comment: Yeah, I'm not keen on that review. It's highly upvoted due to the answer, which distorts things. I've lifted the review ban since it triggered a new suspension solely on that one failed audit.

Comment: Can come for support as I had the same problem. 2 days ban for 2 answers which looked fine from outside.

Comment: @knitti - If you make a habit of opening the actual question in another tab you probably will be able to tell when a review is an audit

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a clear example of why voting should not be considered an action in a review queue.

You failed the first audit because you downvoted the question. Honestly, I would have also downvoted the question, as it needs more details, and the only detail provided is a screenshot.

The system *assumed* the post was high quality because it had a lot of upvotes, but that's not going to work out all the time. Lots of bad posts get upvotes, and lots of good posts get downvotes.

Even if the post was somewhat high quality, one can downvote a post for any reason they want. In fact, the only rule in voting is that it must *not* be targeted at a user.

As for the second audit... well.. that *is* an answer at the end. The reviewers made a mistake in the Low Quality Posts queue, because that is not NAA.

To sum it up, I really like what [@nbk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk) [said in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407502/failed-first-posts-review-audits-are-not-cleared-after-suspension-period-has-end#comment841881_407502):

> no, the review system is not fine. It asks for an opinion and expects that all have the same view on it,. which is fundamentally systemic wrong

*Voting is an opinion-based action. It should not be enforced by a boolean.*

Comment: I feel like if the "bad" vote direction (down on a "good" post, up on a "bad") *didn't* fail the audit, then this would be a non-issue. I don't like counting an upvote on a good-post audit as a pass, but if the opposite was counted as a *neutral* action rather than a fail, we'd have fewer cases where good-faith reviewers fail audits for bad reasons.

Comment: @zcoop98 yeah, that's true. I actually did fail an audit once where the post was supposedly high quality, but I disagreed with it and downvoted the post.

Comment: Regarding the first audit example, I'm not sure that I see the value in a simple downvote. What does a new poster gain from this? It basically just tells him… you suck. Wouldn't it be more useful to provide some guidance towards improving the question? I just recently gained access to the review queues (on another site) and am trying to figure this out. At this point, I skip most of the posts I review.

Comment: @Mockman a downvote does not equate to "you suck". It equates to "This post needs improvement. And most people (myself included) do not comment after downvoting in fear of retaliation.

Comment: For someone making their first post, I think it is more likely to be perceived as 'you suck' as it has no context. I'm not sure that intent matters. That people have to consider retaliation sucks on its own but wouldn't a constructive comment without a downvote have more value than an unexplained downvote? (assuming a non-egregious post)

Comment: @Mockman if a new user will take a downvote offensively, then that is not anyone's problem except theirs. There is a tooltip that explains what a downvote is. And there are a lot of users who comment constructively but still get retaliation. At the end of the day, it is the users choice on whether they comment while downvoting. And a downvote also sends a signal to other users that the post is Low qualty.

Comment: @Mockman there are some users who comment without downvoting. I've tried it a few times when I am reviewing in the LQP and all that happened was... nothing. I followed the post, and my feedback was not observed. A downvote is the thing that sends the messge that this post needs to be fixed.

Comment: And either way, that's not the point of this post. The point is that our review audit system is kind of broken.

Comment: Didn't mean to highjack your post. I thought that its opening sentence stated my own opinion succinctly and so I commented.

Comment: The broken review system has gone on long enough. It's time to start recommending detecting and skipping reviews until it is fixed.

Comment: @Joshua the site would fall down onto it's knees if people stopped reviewing the close votes queue as much as they do now.

Comment: @10Rep: I had intended to write "skipping review audits" but the owners don't understand anymore so maybe letting the site get messed up if they don't fix something is the only way to really get something fixed.

Answer (score 19):

Generally, the functionality you're describing is reasonable: assuming the audits were correct, you were suspended due to failing two audits, then again for failing to learn from your initial suspension when you failed the third.  The ban was because you failed these three audits close together.  Someone who legitimately fails three valid audits like this *should* be suspended again.

The problem is, of course, that all three of your audits were at least arguably *wrong*.  Your review of each of them was valid.  So while your suspension *is* unreasonable, it's not because it counted the audits from before your suspension; it's because it suspended you over invalid audits.

Answer (score 15):

> I want to understand why the system works the way it works.

You've been subjected to (IMO) one of the most significant flaws of our current review system (at least in the First Posts & Late Answers queues). First though, here's some context.

#### Why Audits?

[Our review audit system is designed to encourage folks not to "robo-review,"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#what-is-the-purpose-of-this-test) that is, to think critically about the posts that they review, to take the task of reviewing posts seriously, and not to go on auto-pilot while making choices about the fate of posts and other content on the site.

This is all fine and good– it makes a lot of sense to have a system that does this. The audit system was born out of necessity, coming about shortly after badges for review tasks were introduced:

> Let's also talk about the term "robo-reviewer" that I see being tossed around. This came about during our brief, horrible period between when badges for review were introduced and when the audits were implemented. During that period, there were a number of people who gamed the system by clicking buttons in review as quickly as they could in order to rack up badges.
>
> The audits have largely done away with these people. [. . .]
> <sub>– [@Brad Larson♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson), [answered Jun 12 '14 at 15:17](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260323/let-us-bring-an-end-to-the-robo-reviewer-war-phase-3/260350#260350)</sub>

If [audits are supposed to be easy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug), designed only to catch people not paying attention, then those of us who *do* pay attention aren't supposed to have anything to worry about! But alas, this clearly isn't the case. The obvious problem here is the gap between what audits are *designed* to do, and what they *actually* do in practice, at least sometimes.

#### When Audits Go Bad

In this case, as with many [other bad audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits), you *did* think critically about the posts in question. You compared them with our [defined quality standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts), recognized some qualities in them that made them good or bad, and then took an encouraged curation action on those posts. And then... you were *penalized* for it, because you came to a conclusion that conflicted with how the system interpreted that same post.

What makes this situation even worse is that the action you took wasn't even a "review" action, but a general curation one– you **voted**! Why are we penalizing people for taking [an action which is recognized as inherently subjective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture)? Besides, voting is an easily reversible action, why should a review audit complete (whether pass *or* fail) for anything other than *submitting the review*? Isn't that what we're trying to test and train for here?

...

The system clearly isn't perfect. In fact, I would argue that this is one of the ways in which it is *badly* flawed, an instance where it penalizes good actors with a quirk that does little to punish or weed out bad ones.

I don't have a specific source for this (if someone has one, by all means let me know), but I strongly suspect that audits were designed to take votes into account because they're easy to associate as "good" or "bad". "Audit is a good post? Well obviously upvotes should pass! Downvote a known-good post audit? Fail for you!" That logic is simple and makes practical sense; at least until you take into account the outlier posts, which may not be strictly good *or* bad, and which don't really have business being audits in the first place.

#### Stepping Forward

At the end of the day, it's worth mentioning– **you are very clearly not a robo-reviewer**. After all, that *is* what we're aiming to guard against here, however imperfectly. Take pride in that, as we're always in need of more critical thinkers, whether in the review queues, around the site, or in the world at large.

Many reviewers more experienced than I will reassure you that the system does work well, *most* of the time. And clearly, if good reviewers were being constantly suspended left and right, we would see this reflected in a decline in the overall quality of content on the site, which I don't think is the case.

Continue to be careful when reviewing, continue to report bad audits here on Meta, and don't be afraid to take a break from the review queues to avoid future suspensions if you'd like– the queues on Stack Overflow certainly aren't in danger of running dry anytime soon. They'll be ready for you whenever you do decide to dive back in!

---

Related Reading:

- [Thesis: a downvote should never fail a first post audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit) – Meta Stack Overflow
- [“STOP! Look and Listen” audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me) – Meta Stack Exchange
- [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) – Meta Stack Overflow <sup>(Has since been addressed)</sup>

Comment: One more problem I see is the following: how are users supposed to learn and practice to review when they are blocked? Being presented with questionable audits doesn't help in learning and not being able to review at all for days or weeks does not make users better reviewers (Why would they become better at reviewing and how could they become improve? They cannot practice)

Comment: Having peace of mind about not being a robo-reviewer does not really help in keeping the motivation up to improve the site's quality through review, knowing that after the 4 days are over I will get suspended for 8 days, if I fail an audit on the last day of the "cooldown phase" in 33 days (4+29). After that, one failed audit after 37 (8+29) days = suspension for 16 days

Comment: @knittl Review suspending users have in many cases made them go and find out how to review. Having a "cool down" period seems to have motivated them to "read the manual". Especially the many meta posts about it. The bigger issue is that there is no training ground. I believe the idea was that it's better to have users not review than them reviewing wrongly.

Comment: @Scratte, That's perfect *in spirit*. And I agree with the intention. But what I learned was how to 'game' the system to spot an audit. It's part of the reason why I've generally stopped reviewing on SE. It just seems like I'm playing a computer game instead of trying to help improve the site. If the sole goal is to stop robo reviewers, then I guess they've got that part sorted. But it feels like something in the system needs a bit more of a human touch to it to make it LOT better.

Comment: The audit system is broken. Has been for a long time. @outlak's comment is spot on..."It just seems like I'm playing a computer game instead of trying to help improve the site".

Comment: @knittl 16 days is not that much. I've been review suspended for 5 months before a mod kindly reset it. And some people get banned _forever_ from the queues. It's harsh, to say the least.